# Update position in Firebase Real Time Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I have one Table User look

> User
>   
> Id  | name | email | Latitude | Longitude

I would like update Position this user in Real Time in Firebase, I'm user the method WatchPosition, but how to update position in real time, follow my code in the TS

```
addPosition() {
let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
watch.subscribe((data) => {

  this.myPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude);

      this.mapOptions = {
        zoom: 19,
        center: this.myPosition,
        disableDefaultUI: true
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), this.mapOptions);
      this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

      this.addMarker(this.myPosition);

      const request = {
            // Pode ser uma coordenada (LatLng), uma string ou um lugar
            origin: this.myPosition,
            // origin: new google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude),
            destination: new google.maps.LatLng('-1.376040', '-48.435644'),
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          };
          this.traceRoute(this.directionsService, this.directionsDisplay, request);
      })
 }
```

Comment: do you mean, that you want to use `update()`? This: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields?

Comment: Look, we have 2 characters in this situation, one is a driver and the other is pedestrian, the pedestrian need see the driver in moviment in real time in the map I never did it, I don't know if we use update or now, how to do ?   I need to do that the driver move on in the map and pedestrin need see it...